# Routing and multiple views in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

Am trying to display on a page client list but for some reason its not working .. i think its something to do with 'ngRoute'

structure:

-root
index.html

- bower_components
- css
- js
  main.js
- templates
  footer.html
  header.html
- views
  clients.html
  home.html
  templates.html

  - partials
    clientList.html

index.html

```
<body ng-app="emailBuilder">
    <div ng-include='"templates/header.html"'></div>
    <div ng-view></div>
    <div ng-include='"templates/footer.html"'></div>
</body>
```

main.js

```
var app = angular.module('emailBuilder', [
  'ngRoute'
]);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
 .when("/", {templateUrl: "views/home.html", controller: "PageCtrl"})
 .when("/clients", {templateUrl: "views/clients.html", controller: "PageCtrl"})
 .when("/templates", {templateUrl: "views/templates.html", controller: "PageCtrl"})
 .otherwise("/404", {templateUrl: "views/404.html", controller:"PageCtrl"});
}]);

app.controller("PageCtrl", function($scope){
    $scope.clients = [
        { name: "clientName", template: "templateName", logo: "logo1"},
        { name: "clientName2", template: "templatename2", logo: "logo2"},
    ];
});
```

clientList.html

```
<div class="client">
    <img ng-src="{{client.logo}}.jpg" width="15" />
    {{client.name}}<br /> {{client.template}} 
</div>
```

clients.html

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h1 class="page-header">Clients
            <small>Choose a client</small>
        </h1>
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="active">Clients</li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <h3>Clients</h3>
    <div ng-controller="PageCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="client in clients" ng-include="views/partials/clientList.html">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide the logged error in console?

Comment: there is no no errors

Comment: hello. if you not received errors. What do you see when for example try get http://localhost/clients? just empty page?

Comment: on clients page i see h3-clients but it doesn't load client list

Answer (score 0):

In your case I see you are trying to use a different controller in the routing part - "PageCtrl" instead of "ClientlistCtrl" .I think if you use the right controller name in the routing, it should solve the issue.

Comment: Ok. Can you try to check if this path is correct? ng-include="views/partials/clientList.html"